# rubocop offense but not sure what is wrong

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I am cleaning up some code that I've inherited and there's this line but to be honest, I'm not sure what rubocop is trying to tell me is wrong with it.

```
  total_cost = tmp_totals.inject { |total, tmp_val| total + tmp_val }
```

I am getting this error

```
app/models/item_count.rb:58:40: C: Name inject block params |acc, elem|
```

that looks like this:

[image]

I am just trying to get past this cop. Any ideas what it is telling me to fix?

Comment: Why not replace the whole line with `total_cost = tmp_totals.inject(:+)` or `total_cost = tmp_totals.sum`? Doesn't really answer the question but it'll make rubucop shut about without going through a bunch of nonsense contortions.

Comment: Don't forget when doing `inject` or `reduce` on lists to have a default value which will handle empty list conditions: `inject(0) { ... }` for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Rubocop wants you to name those two variables `acc` and `elem` instead of `total` and `tmp_val`.  You can configure the variables it wants in your own rubycop.yml.  The defaults are setup like this:

```
Style/SingleLineBlockParams:
  Methods:
    - reduce:
        - acc
        - elem
    - inject:
        - acc
        - elem
```

Comment: Why would this improve code quality? I think `total_cost = totals.inject { |sum, total| sum + total }` is better readable than `total_cost = totals.inject { | acc, elem | acc + elem }`.

Answer (score 1):

Rubocop is a bit too rigid with this one. 
It should just check that the second parameter isn't called `mem` or `acc` IMHO. 
Just use :

`total_cost = tmp_totals.inject(0) { |acc, elem| acc + elem }`

Or

`total_cost = tmp_totals.inject(0, :+)`

Rubocop won't complain, and you'll get 0 instead of nil for an empty array.

If you're not sure what rubocop complains about, you could :

- make sure your code is committed
- use `rubocop -a script.rb`
- check if the code still works
- check what the difference is

Comment: AFAIK `tmp_totals.inject(0, :+)` will also work and will be faster than `&:+`